# Cakephp format url with image and title

Tags: cakephp

i'm tring to change my link into a CakePhp format link. I want aso to add the class "ajax" in my link.

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('images/home.png'),'Accueil', array ('action'=>'index.php'),array('class'=>'ajax')); ?>
```

My original link :

```
 <li><a href="index.php" id="visited"><span class="home">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>images/home.png" alt=""></span>Accueil</a></li>
```

Thanks

Comment: You forgot escape=>false as documented - and as shown in at least 20 other SO questions/answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as mark said and additionally if you want to add the span tag,

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('span', $this->Html->image('images/home.png'), array('class' => 'home', 'escape' => false)).' Accueil', array ('action'=>'index.php'),array('class'=>'ajax', 'escape' => false)); ?></li>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo  $this->Html->tag('li',$this->Html->link( 
                                    $this->Html->tag('span',
                                                    $this->Html->Image('images/home.png',array(
                                                                    'alt'=>'','height'=>'100%','width'=>'100%'
                                                                    )).'Accueil',
                                                    array('class'=>'home')
                                                ),
                                    array(
                                        'controller' =>'','action' => 'index.php'
                                        ),
                                    array(
                                        'class' = 'ajax'
                                        )   
                                )
                    )
```

I have written this for you to learning link & tag building in cakephp....i thinks it helpful for you...............